# Excel: Identifying common groups of properties for IDs

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a load of data of the nature:

| ID | Flavour |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 1 | orange |
| 2 | pear |
| 2 | orange |
| 2 | cucumber |
| 3 | apple |
| ... | ... |

I need to identify the most common groups of flavours (ie. there are 36 IDs with Apple and Orange flavours, 2 with pear and cucumber, and so on)

I currently have a pivot table with the row labels as the IDs so one sees these groups by eye, but I am at a loss on how to count them in a way that makes any sort of sense.

Comment: add IDs to the values section of the pivot table and flavour to the row section, by default it should give you a count, but just google how to use a pivot table you will get many results

Comment: This would I believe give counts of the flavours in each ID, but i'm looking for the most common groups of flavours (so how many IDs have the pairing [apple, orange], how many have just pear, etc.

Comment: then do it the other way round...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the formulas to count the IDs for different groups.

First I suggest you use the formula `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$13=D2,B$2:B$13,""))` to handle data as following. Then one line for one ID.

[image]

Such as for [apple,Orange], please use the formula `=COUNTIF(E2:E5,"*apple*orange*")` to get count.

Such as for [pear], you may use the formula `=COUNTIF(E2:E5,"*pear*")`.

[image]

You may count the group of differen flavours as you want. After get the counts, you may use pivot table or formulas to get the quantity order from high to low.

Comment: You absolutely nailed it, thanks!